# check if an item in weblist is indented or not

Tags: vbscript, qtp

I have list of items in a weblist and which has both parent and child.  Child is indented to the right,  I need to retrieve values of child and parent in two different columns in a datatable.

My code goes like this:

```
list = qtp_getroproperty(page.weblist(), "items count", itemsCount
For n = 1 To itemsCount
  items = page.weblist(), getitem(n)
```

Comment: This looks like an [X-Y Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) to me. You may get better answers if you describe what you *actually* want to achieve by doing this. Sample input might also help.

Comment: In case you think your edit clarifies anything: it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

In VBScript it's [Left()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sk3xcs8k(v=vs.84).aspx):

```
>> For Each s In Array("x", " x", "  x")
>>     WScript.Echo s, CStr(" " = Left(s, 1))
>> Next
>>
x Falsch
 x Wahr
  x Wahr
>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if strSurname.StartsWith(" ")
```

Comment: That's not VBScript.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to go about this:

- Extract the first character with the [`Left`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sk3xcs8k.aspx) function, as [Ekkehard Horner suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43178989/1630171):

  ```
  If Left(str, 1) = " " Then
    ...
  End If
  ```
- Check the first character with the [`InStrRev`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hsxyczeb.aspx) function:

  ```
  If InStrRev(str, " ", 1) > 0 Then
    ...
  End If
  ```
- [`LTrim`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c623wz83.aspx) the string and compare it to the original string:

  ```
  If LTrim(str) <> str Then
    ...
  End If
  ```
- Use a [regular expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y32x2hy1.aspx):

  ```
  Set re = New RegExp
  re.Pattern = "^ "
  If re.Test(str) Then
    ...
  End If
  ```

  Note that this last approach is the most versatile, but also the most expensive. Usually it won't make sense to use this to check for something as simple as "does the string begin with a space". It becomes more useful if for instance you want to check "does the string begin with any kind of whitespace" (`"^\s"`).

Comment: I need to check whether an item in a weblist is indented or not and if indented get the value to datatable as child else as parent

Comment: My code goes like this: list = qtp_getroproperty(page.weblist(), "items count", itemsCount  For n = 1 to itemsCount  items = page.weblist(),getitem(n)

Comment: @renju Please edit your question. You may also want to add the [tag:qtp] tag while you're at it.

Comment: sure, I did edited my question